# Formatar valor de dinheiro vindo do banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, operadores

Tenho um input com uma máscara onde o usuário digita o preço desejado e automaticamente é formatado. Antes de enviar para o banco de dados, transformo esse valor para poder trabalhar com ele com alguma operação aritmética.

Exemplo:

```php
$preco = "2.199,99"

$preco = str_replace(".", "", $preco);
$preco = str_replace(",", ".", $preco);

//No final o valor inserido no banco de dados será 2199.99
```

Esse valor, após cadastrado, aparecerá em uma tabela, gostaria que ele viesse da mesma forma de quando foi formatado. Substituiria novamente o `.` por `,`, mas como irei inserir um `.` para cada três números?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a função `number_format`.

Segue exemplo:

```
$numero = '2199.99';

echo number_format($numero, 2, ',', '.'); // Resultado: 2.199,99
```

Documentação: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php

Comment: Não conhecia esta função, obrigado!